# Preload images android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, preload

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.v(StartupActivity.TAG, "SURFACE CREATED");
    bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    bitmaps.put("logo", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo));
    displayLoadingBitmap();
    bitmaps.remove("logo");
    System.gc();
    ....
}
```

The surface is created immediately but my bitmap appears a little bit late. Is there a way to preload bitmap in for example StartupActivity and send it to the current Activity just to display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can preload that bitmap in the start activity and pass it to the target activity.

In order to send that bitmap, since bitmaps implement `Parceable`, they can be serialized and passed to another activity.

**StartUpActivity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", bitmap);
```

**TargetActivity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
```

Alternatively you're recommended to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library which handles all stuff you would need about caching and fetching images.

Comment: It somehow changes the intent so it is transition between StartupActivity and the same StartupActivity....

Comment: @duri No it's a regular extra that can be passed using Intent. Make sure the `TargetActivity` is set properly.